# Django can't import app from apps' folder, ImportError

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-apps, django-1.11

I have old project made on Django 1.11.10 and Python 2.7

Imports like below aren't working

```
from apps.configuration.utils import HrefModel
```

Traceback

```
 from apps.configuration.utils import HrefModel

 ImportError: No module named configuration.utils
```

Installed apps inside settings

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    some django apps...

    "apps.configuration",
    "apps.nav",
    "apps.pages",

    more similar apps...
]
```

Project's folder structure

```
project_name/
├── apps
│   ├── account
│   ├── administration
│   ├── catalog
│   ├── configuration
│   │     ├── admin.py
│   │     ├── apps.py
│   │     ├── context_processors.py
│   │     ├── __init__.py
│   │     ├── lookups.py
│   │     ├── management
│   │     ├── migrations
│   │     ├── models
│   │     ├── templatetags
│   │     ├── tests.py
│   │     ├── utils
│   │     └── views.py
│   ├── content
│   ├── elastic_search
│   ├── feedback
│   ├── google_captcha
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── nav
│   ├── pages
│   ├── posts
│   ├── shop
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── entrypoint.sh
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
```

utils folder inside configuration app

```
utils/
├── bank.py
├── format.py
├── __init__.py
├── objects.py
├── pagination.py
└── slug.py
```

Objects.py contains the class, that I want to import

Comment: Is `configuration` a folder? Where is `utils.py`? You might be missing a `__init__.py` on the configuration folder.

Comment: `configuration` is folder, `utils.py` are placed inside it
Configuration folder has `__init__.py` inside.

Comment: Which file contains the import statement? The import statement depends on where the "importer" file is.

If you file is inside "apps", maybe this work:

`from .configuration.utils import HrefModel`

Comment: Imprter is based inside app in `apps` folder.
Tried your solution, same error
`from .configuration.utils import HrefModel

  ImportError: No module named configuration.utils`

Comment: Is `utils` a folder? Or do you have `utils.py`?

Comment: Yep, utils is a folder. It has init.py inside and init has imports inside

Comment: There's no "app" in "apps" folder... 

Are you importing from `apps/configuration/apps.py`? In this case, you should use: `from .utils import HrefModel`.

Also, I don't see any "HrefModel" inside the "utils" folder. Is it imported in `utils/__init__.py`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant - importer is based inside "nav" app. The importer is one of the nav's models. Yep, `HrefModel` is imported in utils' init.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed python2.7 to python3.5 and that got me rid of the exception

The Django documentation says

> **Python compatibility**
>  Like Django 1.9, Django 1.10 requires Python 2.7, 3.4, or 3.5

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/1.10/